# How do I use Node.js Cradle with multiple keys?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, key, cradle

I've been trying to use multiple keys in Cradle for a good time, I'm almost giving up since I can't find help anywhere.

I use this query with an HTTP request and it brings me results

```
gps_map/_design/carros/_view/teste?startkey=[353451044986295]&endkey=[353451044986296,{}]&limit=50
```

But I can't realize how do I use Cradle to reach the same results, I've tried

```
var car = 353451044986295;
db.view('carros/teste',{limit:50,startkey:[car],endkey:[car,{}]},function(err,res)
```

and

```
var car = 353451044986295;
db.view('carros/teste',{limit:50,startkey:'['+car+']',endkey:'['+car+',{}]'},function(err,res)
```

and have no success, there's no result. How do I use multiple keys in Cradle?

Comment: None, it simple doesn't find any results

Answer (score 1):

Look in your couchdb log to see what request is actually being made to the database.
Chances are the request string being generated isn't what you expect.
You might also need to set descending=true?

Comment: I've give up on cradle and moved on. I'm using a bare http request, it just fit my purposes

Comment: looking at the log really helped me. http://<yourcouchurl>/_log    no database in the url, just the root + _log

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked for me:

CoffeeScript version:

```
filterRange =
    startkey:[100]
    endkey:[400]

@dbClient.view 'business/customers', filterRange, (err, results, fields) =>
    if err
        throw err
```

JavaScript version:

```
var filterRange, _this = this;
filterRange = {
    startkey: ["business_9ba1b5c72af4072b2885b10d36000fa0"],
    endkey: ["business_9ba1b5c72af4072b2885b10d36000fa0", {}]
};

this.dbClient.view('business/customers', filterRange, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err
};
```